# Why do i get : Must use destructuring state assignment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

In my react component I have a constructor:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { rows: [{ prior_year: 1000, current_year: 2000 }] };
  }
```

In my render I have:

```
  <Table>
    {this.state.rows.map(row => (
      <Tr>
        <Td>{row.prior_year}</Td>
        <Td>{row.current_year}</Td>
      </Tr>
    ))}

    <Button onClick={() => this.handleAddAdjustment()} label="Add another adjustment" />
  </Table>
```

Why do I get this lint error: must use destructuring state assignment?

Answer (score 0):

That is just a linter that is telling you to use your `this.state.rows` with something like `const { rows } = this.state ;`. That means whenever you want to use an object property, you de-structure it first and then use it.

for example, this is another example and mostly used in functional react components.

```
const MyFunctionalReactComponent = ({id}) => {
  return (<div id={id} />)
};
```

you can also write it as

```
const MyFunctionalReactComponent = (props) => {
  return (<div id={props.id} />)
};
```

See here for more details, https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md

**Why:** This is very neat and clean way to code as you will be de-structuring all the variables in one line and avoiding `this.state` every time you use a new state variable.